# What types are python xmlrpc objects?

Tags: python, types, python-2.7, xml-rpc

I define a python `xmlrpc` server as follows (approximate example for the purpose of explaining things only):

```
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer
server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(('localhost', 8000))
server.register_function(foo, "serial.send")
server.serve_forever()
```

Then I can use a `xmlrpc` client like the following

```
import xmlrpclib
device = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://localhost:8000/RPC2")
device.serial.send(...)
```

Here I can check if `device` is an instance of `xmlrpclib.ServerProxy` with

```
isinstance(device, xmlrpclib.ServerProxy)
```

but what is `device.serial`? I want to check that `device.serial` belongs to an `xmlrpc`, and not, for instance, to `serial`, `socket` or something else.

Here is a concrete example of what I want to check:

```
def foo(x):
   if isinstance(x, ...):
       print("xmlrpc access")
   else:
       print("direct access")

foo(device.serial) # expected output: 'xmlrpc access'
foo(serial.Serial(..)) # expected output: 'direct access'
foo(socket.Socket(...)) # expected outcome: 'direct access'
```

Comment: Seems as if you have absolutely no understanding what XMLRPC is actually doing. Why should you have access to server-side datastructures and types in a transparent way on the client-side??

Comment: Isn't this sufficient `type(object_name)` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking for arbitrary inspection of Python objects then use the 'inspect' 
module of Python:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-pyint/index.html

also checking

```
>> obj.__class__
```

or

```
>> obj.__class__.__bases__
```

gives you access to the base classes.

Comment: Please see the updated question. But I guess using `obj.__class__` is the answer to my question. THANKS